# Directory indexes are not allowed here. I`m trying to solve this error but nothing any solution

Tags: python, html, django

**Here Is My Code for trying to view pdf file by pressing button.How to solve this problem please add some reply for solving this problem thank you advance..**

here is my views.py code :

```
def show(request):
     a=student.objects.all()
     return render(request,'show.html',{'a':a})

def ppts(request, id):
    b=student.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request,'ppts.html',{'b':b})
```

And Here is my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <td><embed src="{% static ' ' %}{{a.resume}} " height="700px" width="1500px"></td>  
    <!-- <td>  <a href="" download></a>  </td> -->
</body>
</html>
```

And Here is my show.html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
   
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=>, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>student table</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
               
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>ADDRESS</th>
                <th>AGE</th>
                <th>EDUCATION</th>
                <th>EMAIL</th>
                <th>RESUME</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for val in a %}
            <tr>
              
                <td>{{val.NAME}}</td>
                <td>{{val.ADDRESS}}</td>
                <td>{{val.AGE}}</td>
                <td>{{val.EDUCATION}}</td>
                <td>{{val.EMAIL}}</td>
                <td><button><a href="/ppts/{{val.id}}/">{{val.resume}}</a></button></td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

[here is output showing while run this program..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACD9s.png)

Comment: What's your django version ? Did you define the STATIC_URL setting ?

Comment: @DylanKas My Django Version 4.0.4 and yes,I Define Static URL Setting..

Comment: Whats the value of STATIC_URL ?

Comment: What should `src="{% static ' ' %}{{a.resume}} "` mean? You're trying to create a URL with a space and append something to it. Django URL resolving system and static files serving works [not like this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/). Do not create static/media URLs manually. Same problem with `<a href=...` in second template, do not resolve URLs manually. Add method `get_absolute_url` to your model and put it in template as `val.get_absolute_url` (callables are called in template).

Comment: And `a.resume` file is saved as media, not static. It should be `a.resume.path` probably (but make sure that `a.resume` is required, otherwise students with empty resume will have empty link here).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.